# Determining maximum possible alignment in C++

Tags: c++, alignment, c++11

Is there any *portable* way to determine what the maximum possible alignment for *any* type is?

For example on x86, SSE instructions require 16-byte alignment, but as far as I'm aware, no instructions require more than that, so any type can be safely stored into a 16-byte aligned buffer.

I need to create a buffer (such as a char array) where I can write objects of arbitrary types, and so I need to be able to rely on the beginning of the buffer to be aligned.

If all else fails, I know that allocating a char array with `new` is guaranteed to have maximum alignment, but with the TR1/C++0x templates `alignment_of` and `aligned_storage`, I am wondering if it would be possible to create the buffer in-place in my buffer class, rather than requiring the extra pointer indirection of a dynamically allocated array.

Ideas?

I realize there are plenty of options for determining the max alignment for a bounded set of types: A union, or just `alignment_of` from TR1, but my problem is that the set of types is unbounded. I don't know in advance which objects must be stored into the buffer.

Comment: portable in what regard, exactly? to each compiler? to each OS? to each architecture?

Comment: Just portable as in "guaranteed by the C++ standard to work". Of course, I could easily rely on my own knowledge of the target architecture and hardcode the max alignment, but it would be nice if the language itself provided the tools to answer this.

Comment: Note that the `Align` template parameter of `std::aligned_storage<Len, Align>` has a default argument of "default-alignment," which is defined as "The value of default-alignment shall be the most stringent alignment requirement for any C++ object type whose size is no greater than `Len`."  I don't know whether SSE types are considered "C++ object types," and the VC10 Standard Library doesn't have the default argument, so I don't know what the intended value is (I don't have any other Standard Library implementations on this machine).

Comment: @James: Oh wow, that should solve it. Nice find. I just tested it with GCC, and it does seem to default to 16 on x86, which would allow for SSE types as well as any other. I you make that an answer, I'll accept that. :)

Comment: Better 14 months late than never, eh?  ;-)

Comment: New instruction sets require bigger alignments - AVX/AVX2 needs 32-byte alignment, and AVX512 needs 64-byte alignment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C++0x, the `Align` template parameter of `std::aligned_storage<Len, Align>` has a default argument of "default-alignment," which is defined as (N3225 §20.7.6.6 Table 56):

> The value of default-alignment shall be the most stringent alignment requirement for any C++ object type whose size is no greater than `Len`.

It isn't clear whether SSE types would be considered "C++ object types."

The default argument wasn't part of the TR1 `aligned_storage`; it was added for C++0x.

Answer (score 15):

In C++11 std::max_align_t defined in header cstddef is a POD type whose alignment requirement is at least as strict (as large) as that of every scalar type.

Using the new alignof operator it would be as simple as `alignof(std::max_align_t)`

Comment: for compilers that don't support alignof (i.e. MSVC11), you can use std::alignment_of<std::max_align_t>::value

Comment: This works great until there's [a bug in the standard library](https://github.com/cameron314/concurrentqueue/issues/64) :-/

Comment: And structs aren't scalar types, anyway.  It might be the case that `new`, in order to properly align non-scalars, uses a stricter alignment than `std::max_align_t`.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately ensuring max alignment is a lot tougher than it should be, and there are no guaranteed solutions AFAIK. From the [GotW](http://www.gotw.ca/) blog ([Fast Pimpl article](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/028.htm)):

```
union max_align {
  short       dummy0;
  long        dummy1;
  double      dummy2;
  long double dummy3;
  void*       dummy4;
  /*...and pointers to functions, pointers to
       member functions, pointers to member data,
       pointers to classes, eye of newt, ...*/
};

union {
  max_align m;
  char x_[sizeofx];
};
```

> This isn't guaranteed to be fully
>   portable, but in practice it's close
>   enough because there are few or no
>   systems on which this won't work as
>   expected.

That's about the closest 'hack' I know for this.

There is another approach that I've used personally for super fast allocation. Note that it is evil, but I work in raytracing fields where speed is one of the greatest measures of quality and we profile code on a daily basis. It involves using a heap allocator with pre-allocated memory that works like the local stack (just increments a pointer on allocation and decrements one on deallocation).

I use it for [Pimpls](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom) particularly. However, just having the allocator is not enough; for such an allocator to work, we have to assume that memory for a class, Foo, is allocated in a constructor, the same memory is likewise deallocated only in the destructor, and that Foo itself is created on the stack. To make it safe, I needed a function to see if the 'this' pointer of a class is on the local stack to determine if we can use our super fast heap-based stack allocator. For that we had to research OS-specific solutions: I used [TIBs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block) and [TEBs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block) for Win32/Win64, and my co-workers found solutions for Linux and Mac OS X.

The result, after a week of researching OS-specific methods to detect stack range, alignment requirements, and doing a lot of testing and profiling, was an allocator that could allocate memory in 4 clock cycles according to our tick counter benchmarks as opposed to about 400 cycles for malloc/operator new (our test involved thread contention so malloc is likely to be a bit faster than this in single-threaded cases, perhaps a couple of hundred cycles). We added a per-thread heap stack and detected which thread was being used which increased the time to about 12 cycles, though the client can keep track of the thread allocator to get the 4 cycle allocations. It wiped out memory allocation based hotspots off the map.

While you don't have to go through all that trouble, writing a fast allocator might be easier and more generally applicable (ex: allowing the amount of memory to allocate/deallocate to be determined at runtime) than something like `max_align` here. `max_align` is easy enough to use, but if you're after speed for memory allocations (and assuming you've already profiled your code and found hotspots in malloc/free/operator new/delete with major contributors being in code you have control over), writing your own allocator can really make the difference.

Comment: +1. Wow, 100 times faster allocation. Thanks for sharing this information.

Comment: Hmm, that's very interesting. But I wasn't really asking about fast allocation (In my case, that's actually a fairly easy problem to solve, because I don't have to handle the nasty general cases like you did -- and I must say, I'm impressed you got it working). But my question was simply about ensuring that objects are allocated at correctly aligned addresses.

Comment: @jalf Ah, apologies, typically I think when one starts going into alignment issues and storing various data types into a single buffer, it's often with a memory allocator and performance in mind. I'm afraid I don't know of any portable way to ensure max alignment for a given type. Typically I've had to get quite platform-specific in such cases. To try to get it safe, I've often used opt-in approaches (a type whose alignment is unknown will get aligned on double quadword boundaries, the maximum possible alignment I'm aware of).

Comment: @jalf ... this way I have to get platform-specific (would love to be able to avoid this) but I'm reasonably safe assuming that double quadword alignment, while potentially being wasteful, will not cause problems since I use it by default for an unknown type, T, whose alignment has not been registered.

Answer (score 5):

Short of some `maximally_aligned_t` type that all compilers promised faithfully to support for all architectures everywhere, I don't see how this could be solved at compile time.  As you say, the set of potential types is unbounded.  Is the extra pointer indirection really that big a deal?

Comment: It might not be, but I'm curious if there is a solution. C++0x adds a couple of other alignment-related functions, and the implementation already has to determine the maximum possible alignment in other cases (when dynamically allocating a char array) so I thought there might be some obscure standard library template which exposes this value.

Comment: Yeah.  It's an interesting question, and I wish I had a better answer for you, but I don't think there's any standards-conformant way.  maximally_aligned_t (or better, maximal_alignment) wouldn't be hard to implement, though; perhaps you should propose it for c++1x :)

Comment: As other answers mention, as of C11 there is such a type: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/max_align_t See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc

Answer (score 1):

Allocating aligned memory is trickier than it looks - see for example *[Implementation of aligned memory allocation](http://jongampark.wordpress.com/2008/06/12/implementation-of-aligned-memory-alloc/)*

Comment: I know it's tricky. That wasn't my question. ;)
But the standard does give some guarantees, and especially when you take C++0x into account, you do have a couple of *standard* tools to help out.

Comment: The trickiness doesn't apply to Jalf because he's not making a general allocator. All he needs is to have extra space in his buffer, and round up the in-buffer pointer to the next desired alignment block.

Answer (score -2):

This is what I'm using.  In addition to this, if you're allocating memory then a new()'d array of char with length greater than or equal to max_alignment will be aligned to max_alignment so you can then use indexes into that array to get aligned addresses.

```
enum {
            max_alignment = boost::mpl::deref<
                boost::mpl::max_element<
                        boost::mpl::vector<
                            boost::mpl::int_<boost::alignment_of<signed char>::value>::type,
                            boost::mpl::int_<boost::alignment_of<short int>::value>::type,
                            boost::mpl::int_<boost::alignment_of<int>::value>::type,                                boost::mpl::int_<boost::alignment_of<long int>::value>::type,
                            boost::mpl::int_<boost::alignment_of<float>::value>::type,
                            boost::mpl::int_<boost::alignment_of<double>::value>::type,
                            boost::mpl::int_<boost::alignment_of<long double>::value>::type,
                            boost::mpl::int_<boost::alignment_of<void*>::value>::type
                        >::type
                    >::type
                >::type::value
            };
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't ensure suitable alignment for SSE types.