# What's the biggest data type in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I searched about biggest data type in c++, but each site wrote different data types. If there is an expert, can he (she) write answer. It's important.
Thanks.

Comment: `(unsigned) long long`

Comment: What about `std::intmax_t`?

Comment: some sites wrote long double...

Comment: Ah, `long double` could be bigger by byte count (I think it's usually either 64-bit or 80-bit floating point), but it's a different type of data type (floating point instead of integer)

Comment: Do you mean basic data type? Because your structs can be as big as you want.

Comment: Yes, biggest basic data type.

Comment: Just [look at the existing fundamental types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types), and then write a simple program that checks the sizes using `sizeof`? That will show you the "biggest" for *your* compiler on *your* system.

Comment: I finally downvoted your question. You did not motivate it enough.... and I hoped you would edit it to improve it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch what do you mean by "...did not motivate it enough..."?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It (the largest size of scalar types) is **implementation specific**.

You might have some weird implementation with 64 bits-wide `char`, and `sizeof(char)`, `sizeof(int)`, `sizeof(long)`, `sizeof(long long)`, `sizeof(void*)` all being 1.

I know no such implementation of C++11, but I heard of a bizarre C99 implementation above [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) doing similar things. I might be wrong.

AFAIK, `long long` should be at least 64 bits wide. And `long double` is often wider than that (but I don't know what is it *required* by the standard to be).

Also, an implementation can have extra (and specific) builtin types, e.g. `_int128_t` on *some recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)*

If you care about the biggest alignment, it is a slightly different question, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1527680/841108). (and 16 bytes is a good alignment on [x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64), e.g. because of [AVX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions)).

Of course aggregates (e.g. `struct` or arrays) can have quite big sizes (and on GCC, larger alignment than builtin types).

The *practical* biggest size of aggregates is certainly limited by the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) (so a few gigabytes on tablets or laptops, and many terabytes or even petabytes if you are rich enough to have access to some costly supercomputer).

However, the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) is *practically* often limited to a few megabytes (or gigabytes on a costly supercomputer). So huge data structures are better allocated on the heap (notice that STL containers like `std::vector` often allocate most of their data in heap, even when the container is a local variable).

Concretely, be cautious when allocating on heap a contiguous zone above a few gigabytes (that might fail on your tablet).

Comment: Is there a difference between sizeof(long long) and long long ?

Comment: @BarishNamazov Yes, they are not the same thing??

Comment: @BarishNamazov You mean besides the fact that one is an expression that returns a size, and the other is a type?

Comment: The  `sizeof` is a compile-time operator giving some integral constant of type `size_t` (e.g. 4 or 8 etc....), the `long long` is a type. You are comparing apples and wine bottles!

Comment: Mmmm... wine bottles.

Comment: FYI, long double usually is larger than long long and occupies 96 bits.

Comment: @NeilKirk: I am not a native English speaker, but the difference is even larger than apples and oranges (both are eatable fruits)

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you can't get a type bigger than this:

```
struct Big
{
    char buf[static_cast<size_t>(-1)];
};
```

Comment: Would -1 be better some `LONG_LONG_MAX`

Comment: how about `struct Bigger { char buf[static_cast<size_t>(-1)]; char more_buf[static_cast<size_t>(-1)]; };` where `size_t` is smaller than `uintptr_t`... if that's possible... maybe with... segmented addressing? ... idk, I'm just randomly poking fun.

Comment: @bolov Well so long as `sizeof` returns maximum, any extra stuff is superfluous.

Comment: yep, found this: `A type whose size cannot be represented by std::size_t is ill-formed (since C++14)` Which proves that your struct is the maximum possible size, at least since C++14. [size_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t)